# How do I generate new JSON files that may contain a single quote from an old JSON file

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I've written some code which has to read through 5,000 JSON files and replace a number which appears twice in each file. It's set to create a new json file and delete the old one, with that, other data must be transferred into the new file too, which is not a problem, however we have a list called `attributes` that contain some text that use single quotes (for punctuation.) - however when the new json file is written, the text with the single quotes is changed and the single quote is replaced with `\u0027`

Example: old file contains:`"0.png"` and `"Hen's Secret Bra"` which in the new file is changing to `"5000.png"` correct, and `"Hen\u0027s Secret Bra"` incorrect. How do I transfer the single quote over properly?

Here is my code:

```
    using System.Text.Json;
    using System.Web;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
   
{
    //get all the json files
    var jsonPath = @"/Users/jasonnienaber/Desktop/nft/cef/official/fatJSONselfFIX/test";
    var jsonFiles = Directory.GetFiles(jsonPath, "*.json");

    //loop through each file and process according to specs
    foreach(var jsonFile in jsonFiles)
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
        var sample = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Sample>(json);
        var sampleNew = new SampleNew();
        var intCounter = 0;
        var newIntCounter = intCounter+5000;
        var Counter = intCounter.ToString();
        var newCounter = newIntCounter.ToString();

       sampleNew.image = sample.image.Replace(Counter, newCounter);
       sampleNew.name = sample.name.Replace(Counter, newCounter);
       sampleNew.description = sample.description;
       sampleNew.external_url = sample.external_url;
       sampleNew.attributes = sample.attributes;

        // serialize JSON to a string and then write string to a file
        File.Delete(jsonFile);
        File.WriteAllText(jsonFile, JsonSerializer.Serialize(sampleNew));
        intCounter++;
        
    }

            
}    
        public class Attribute
        {
            public string trait_type { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }
    
        }
    
        public class Sample
        {
           // public string dna { get; set; }
            public string image { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string external_url { get; set; }
            public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
            public string compiler { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class SampleNew
        {
            public string image { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string external_url { get; set; }
            //public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }

            public List<Attribute> attributes {get; set;}
        }
}
```

The `"Hen's Secret Bra"` is within attributes

Comment: It's entirely valid JSON to use `\u0027`, and System.Text.Json is doing that for security reasons. What *problem* is the escaping causing for you?

Comment: @JonSkeet Understandably so, but when my JSON file is read, will the system read `\u0027` as a single quote again? I don't want the characters \u0027 to appear on OpenSea

Comment: Unless the JSON parser is completely broken, yes. The two *should* be semantically equivalent.

Comment: "`"Hen\u0027s Secret Bra"` incorrect" why?

Comment: @charlieface I need the single quotes to appear, but if Jon Skeet is correct, then the JSON Parser should automatically replace \u0027 with a single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) mentioned, it's valid to use `\u0027`, however, you can change the serializer [encoding options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-6.0):

```
using System.Text.Json;

var obj = new
{
    Name = "John's awesome object",
    Age = 31
};

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
};

// writes obj to json file
File.WriteAllText("obj.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, options));
```

Outputs

```
{"Name":"John's awesome object","Age":31}
```

So in your code, you can do as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
};

//loop through each file and process according to specs
foreach (var jsonFile in jsonFiles)
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
    var sample = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Sample>(json);
    var sampleNew = new SampleNew();
    var intCounter = 0;
    var newIntCounter = intCounter + 5000;
    var Counter = intCounter.ToString();
    var newCounter = newIntCounter.ToString();

    sampleNew.image = sample.image.Replace(Counter, newCounter);
    sampleNew.name = sample.name.Replace(Counter, newCounter);
    sampleNew.description = sample.description;
    sampleNew.external_url = sample.external_url;
    sampleNew.attributes = sample.attributes;

    // serialize JSON to a string and then write string to a file
    File.Delete(jsonFile);
    // use serializer options
    File.WriteAllText(jsonFile, JsonSerializer.Serialize(sampleNew, options));
    intCounter++;
}
```

See [UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder.unsaferelaxedjsonescaping?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use Newtonsoft.Json to avoid any problems like this one.

But one of the thing you can try to fix an issue is  to use a serialize options

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
};
```

but it is unsafe

Another option is more awkward but more safe, since it affects only one symbol, not any as in the first case

```
     var attr= new Attribute{trait_type="trait_type", value="Hen's Secret Bra"};    

    attr.value=attr.value.Replace("'","==="); //or you can try something else if you don't like ===

    var json=System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(attr);

    json=json.Replace("===","'");
    
     File.WriteAllText(jsonFile, json);
     
     json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
```

result

```
{"trait_type":"trait_type","value":"Hen's Secret Bra"}
```